# Will apps developed for WP 7.1 work on WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have already developed an app targeting Windows Phone 8, but it doesn't work on Windows Phone 7.5. To get it working on both platforms, I have decided to target Windows Phone OS 7.1 via Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 instead.

Will my app works on both WP 7.5 and WP 8 if I target WP OS 7.1 in VS 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone applications are forward compatible. This means that applications built for Windows Phone 7.x should work on Windows Phone 8. However, this is not a guarantee. Some applications may not work properly and you should definitely test your application on Windows Phone 8 devices.

You can also maintain two versions of your application: one for Windows Phone 7 and one for Windows Phone 8. You publish both versions as one application so that users of each device can get the best application for their device.

You can upgrade Windows Phone 7 project to Windows Phone 8 project, but you cannot downgrade. The best thing to do is to create a new Windows Phone 7 project and move all files from the WP8 project to the new one.

Answer (score 2):

WP 7.1 (sdk) == WP 7.5 (consumer designation) and yes, WP 7.x apps work on WP 8 devices.

Just for clatification, WP8 and Windows 8 are two different things. If you have a Windows 8  app it will not run on WP 8 or WP 7.x.

Comment: but i have an app for win 8. how to downgrade to wp7 from that ?

Comment: is your current App for Windows 8 or for Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 2):

yes your app will work on both paltforms..

if you develop an app for wp8 then it wont be able to run on wp7.x but vice versa will work fine but it wont be able to use the new features introduced in wp8

Comment: but i have an app for win 8. how to downgrade to wp7 from that ?

Comment: It is not quite true that you cannot use new features introduced in WP8. You *can* use some of the new features via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can develop app that will target both platforms refer following link for detail...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206997%28v=vs.105%29.aspx