# Windows Phone 8.1 app not working with windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have developed windows phone 8.1 that is not working with other platforms.

Is there any way to develop windows phone app that works with all windows phone platforms link 7,8 and 8.1?

Comment: I think they created a universal app template.  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx

Have you checked there?

Comment: Are universal apps supported by Windows phone 7? I thought the only way to Support all platforms, beginning from wp7, would be to develop a wp 7 app.

Comment: @timtos Universal Apps are not supported by WP7. Like you have said - if you want an app suppoerted by all platforms (WP7.x, 8.x), then you have to write the app for WP7.x.

Comment: Hi Hiren, If you are developing a Open Source project, that you can target to all version of OS. But if it is an APP, You can definitely go with Universal Apps. There are only very less number of users for 7.x or 8.  I hope you did for WP8.1, make it universal, it will be a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

Your app written for WP8.1 won't work on WP7.x - it's different API.

If you want to write an app for all platforms (WP7.x and WP8.x) then you will have to do it with the oldest API - WP7.x. Apps written this way should run on WP8.x devices - some more reference [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18207208/2681948).

Every API has its own *Minimum supported phone* - you will find it at the end of every class/method description at MSDN.